# Mac OS X 10.5 VNC Resolution independent of hardware display

Tags: windows, macos, resolution, display, vnc

Is it possible to set the VNC display resolution that is independent of the hardware resolution when you are using OS X 10.5 Screen Sharing?

I have a macbook and a windows box with 3 monitors. I'd like to use the 3 monitors on my windows box to do work on my macbook when I'm at my desk. When I VNC into the macbook I only get the resolution of the hardware screen (1280x800). Instead I'd like to use two of my monitors on my windows box to display a large VNC screen from my macbook. The scaling options in the VNC clients (TightVNC and Ultr@VNC) do not adjust the actual resolution of the display they just do image processing.

My ultimate goal is for someway to have a virtual display on my windows box that is from my macbook that is independent of the macbook's hardware screen.

Answer (score 1):

haven't tried it, but [coderebel's irapp](http://www.coderebel.com/products/irapp/) might be what you want.

according to the [feature list](http://www.coderebel.com/products/irapp-features-system-requirements/) it has support for "multi-monitor displays (you can assign Mac and PC to different monitors, drag Mac applications across two monitors, and stretch applications across multiple monitors)"